# C# access to static inside class

Tags: c#, .net

what word can i write to access static function inside class? like self:: in php?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give an example of what you're trying to do, in terms of what you're trying to call and from where.

Comment: Is the status function defined in the same class or a different class? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `StaticMethodName(...)` (when inside the class where the static method is defined) or `ClassName.StaticMethodName(...)`.

Comment: @jeroenh: I fixed the typo ~6 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 4):

You just use the type name:

```
static class Test
{

  public static string GetSomething()
  {
    return "Something";
  }

}

string s = Test.GetSomething();
```

If you're in the class already you just call the method.

Comment: What do you mean not pretty? Drop the type name from the call if inside the class, all you need to do is call GetSomething() etc.

Comment: i want show that calling function belongs to current class where it called

Comment: Without an explicit reference to another class then it is assumed that it belongs to the current class or a base class (and you can show inherited calls through the use of the base keyword).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such keyword in C#. You need to use the class name, e.g.

```
MyClass.StaticMember
```

Comment: From inside the class itself, you don't need to specify the classname for a static method (it's not an error though).

Answer (score 0):

Write the name of the class.
For example:

```
public static class MyClass { 
public static void HelloWorld(){}
}
```

And use it like:

```
MyClass.HelloWorld();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your static class is named etc. SampleClass, you can access its functions with SampleClass.YourFunction(); . If you want to call a function in other static method, just use the name of the function .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Discover 
{
    static int myVariable = 1;

    public Discover()
    {
      var test = myVariable;
    }
 }
```